# Is it possible to cut a tikzpicture in half if the picture is too long and display it on two pages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm using tikz (tikzpicture to be precise) to make some "drawings" (trees). The problem is that my "drawing" is too long to fit on one single page (it's too long). I was wondering what was the best way to display it on two (or more) pages :

- crop the picture and display it twice, first half on one page and second on second
- use some option that would allow to display the image on the first page and continue on the second page if the picture is too long... (but how?)
- ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my proposed solution, the picture is put into a macro `\mypicture` which takes rectangle coordinates as parameters. These are used to set the bounding box and clip the picture. This macro is used twice for displaying the picture. Here, I used some overlap between the two parts of the long picture but this can be adjusted easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\mypicture}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw=red,use as bounding box] (#1) rectangle ++(#2);% remove 'draw=red' if you don't want a frame
  \clip (#1) rectangle ++(#2);
  % Here comes the actual picture:
  \foreach \n in {1,...,10}
  {
    \path[fill=red!\the\numexpr10*\n\relax!blue,draw=black]
      (0,\the\numexpr3*\n\relax) circle (2cm) node {\Huge\n};
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\mypicture{-5,15}{10,18}
\clearpage
\mypicture{-5,0}{10,18}

\end{document}
```

> [image]