# Flow chart using Tikz- spanning multiple pages

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a flowchart with Tikz. Since it is a long one, it spans three pages. So after creating a node to stop, I am continuing to the next page using \newpage command. Unfortunately some elements in page 1 are connected to page 2, 3 and vice versa. So when I try to create the arrow connection, it is not possible since the \newpage command comes in between. I am sharing the code with you for info. Could  anyone help me to improve the flowchart so that I could direct the arrows among multiple pages. My sample code is below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node 1
\node 2
........
\draw[arrow] (node1)--(node2)
\draw[arrow] (node2)--(node3)
----
\end tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node 1
\node 2
........
\draw[arrow] (node1)--(node2)
\draw[arrow] (node2)--(node3)
----
\end tikzpicture}
\newpage
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\node 1
\node 2
........
\draw[arrow] (node1)--(node2)
\draw[arrow] (node2)--(node3)
----
\end tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please complete your code so we can compile it! But I'd suggest creating a large chart and then including different parts with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: E.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right.

Comment: Typically you would not draw arrows across page boundaries (you'd run into problems with the printable area of the page anyway), but instead use off-page connectors. See here for an example: http://www.flowhelp.com/flowchart/flowchart_connector_detail.html

Comment: @Gessler Your link is exactly what we did 50 years ago with ForTran flow charting.  When we had a flowchart to large for the page we created a numbered node at the right hand on the first page.  And then a node with the same number on the left side of the continued page.  The major requirement that both nodes are the same distance from the top of the page and have the same number.  This also allowed for a single page to link to more than one following page and for pages to be inter linked.

Comment: A similar question but with a tree instead of a flowchart: [how can make a big tree automatically display in the second page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235158/1952) and [my answer there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235247/1952)

Comment: usual way is to split the flow chart on semantic points (as far as is possible) rather than just on size, and have exit states like `go to chart 3 on page 4` then you can put the different branches of the chart as separate flowcharts.

Comment: Thanks David, I indeed split it into various pages. However, I am not able to connect arrows between them via Latex. This is the issue.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge). Please mark your two questions for merging afterwards

Comment: One possibility is to create using a image using a \savebox, then show cropped versions on several pages with adjustbox.