# Flowchart spanning mutliple pages Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

I created a flowchart which is quite big in Tikz. I spans three pages. I used `\newpage` to create page breaks in between. Some nodes in the first page are connected to the last one and vice versa. So when I try to create arrows to link them, it is not getting connected. Could anyone suggest a better way to create this long flowchart? Outline of the code is as below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(1)[];
\node (2)[];
........
\end {tikzpicture}

\newpage
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\node(3)[];
\node (4)[];
........
\end {tikzpicture}
\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(5)[];
\node(6)[];
........
\end {tikzpicture}

%arrows and flow lines
\draw [arrow] (node1) -- (node2);
\draw [arrow] (node3) -- (node4);
```

Comment: What's the difference with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238156/flow-chart-using-tikz-spanning-multiple-pages?